# Any idea to call AWS KMS service from Windows application ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms, aws-sts

I am working on a Windows application, for the encryption I am using AWS KMS service I am able to encrypt the data but here I am passing the AccessKey and SecretKeyId. Is there any way that I can eliminate hard coding of keys in my code.
I have tried with STS:AssumeRole but for that also we will need keys.

Comment: Do you have a user log-in to your application or is that a standalone application? There are other ways of passing credentials to a client-side app, but they all involve being able to distribute the credentials to your client app (environment variables, system properties, a default credentials file, etc -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html). If you have an explicit or implicit user login (like federation, username/password, etc), you can make a better use of STS or Cognito Identity to get temporary credentials. Please clarify your use case.

Comment: @Viccari Thank you for the answer, I have a windows client-side application that needs to be login with username and password. As I know to get the temporary credentials with STS also we need to pass access key and secret id and application won't accept any third party identity providers like Facebook, Google etc.